# Binary Tree Height Function

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm working on a function to find the height of a binary search tree. I found a method that seems like it should work, but I keep getting this error, and I don't know whats wrong with it: Unhandled exception at 0x00903417 in PA5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Here are my height functions...

```
template <class T>
int BST<T>::height()
{

    return displayHeight(mRootNode);    

}

template <class T>
int BST<T>::displayHeight(BST<T> *node)
{
    if (node = NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int left = displayHeight(node->mLeft);
    int right = displayHeight(node->mRight); 

    if (left > right)
        return 1 + left;
    else
        return 1 + right;
}
```

This is the implementation in the main function...

```
 cout << endl << "height: " << tree.height();
```

If I should include anything else, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote the same code but the answer i get is one more than the required answer.
So to correct that in the null condition it should return -1 and not return 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (node = NULL)
```

should be

```
if (node == NULL)
```

because in C++ `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is the relational operator for comparison.

**Why the crash?**

When you do `if (node = NULL)`, you are assigning `NULL` to node and since NULL is `0` the `if` condition fails. So you go ahead and call the function recursively on the nodes's children. Now suppose `node` was actually NULL when the function was called for the first time, you'll be doing the recursive calls on NULL's left and right children!!! Leading to crash.

Comment: Wow. Man, I just KNEW it would be something like that. Thanks, dude!

Comment: @user1698667: You are welcome. We've all done this :), I see you are new to SO and have not accepted answers to any of the 3 questions you've asked. If you find an answer resolving your issue completely, you can go ahead and accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning null to your node parameter variable in your if statement.

```
if (node = NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
```

should be

```
if(node == NULL) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Method to find the height while creating a tree(BST):For both left subtree and right subtree::

Put the elements you want to put in your binary tree in an array before you create the actual tree.
Calculate the number of elements which are greater than the root, which will be going to the left of the tree and similarly with the right side.

Then while you add the elements to your tree. Everytime set a flag bit to 1 or 0 depending on whether you are adding it to the left subtree or the right.

```
if(root->right && flagleft==1)
     no_left--;
     else if(root->right && flagright==1)
         no_right--;
```

This is while you append a node to the left side.

```
if(root->left && flagl==1)
nl--;
else if(root->left && flagr==1)
nr--;
```

This is while you append a node to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've assigned the node to NULL i.e NULL value is 0 , so condition fails.

do if(node==NULL)
instead of
**if(node=NULL)**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your answer is correct, but it was already posted 4 years ago.